# jQuery Tabs undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm relatively new to javascript and jQuery. I'm working on a web application where I have jQuery tabs in a markdown document. To keep things clean I've kept my javascript in a separate document and not in the markdown. Here is my javascript which is in `tabs.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "div.tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Here is the markdown with embedded html and javascript

```
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/docs.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/tabs.js"></script>
{% include resources.html %}

Requirements
------------------

<body>
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">C#</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Javascript</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <pre class="prettyprint">Some C# code</pre>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <pre class="prettyprint">Some Javascript Code</pre>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

When I run this code on the localhost everything works perfectly fine but when I deploy it I get an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error right after this line: `$( "div.tabs" ).tabs();`

Any ideas why this is happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `tabs.js` being loaded when deployed? Check the network tab and console

Comment: is there any other code in `tabs.js` which might be calling a `noConflict()`

Comment: You can check tabs.js by loading it by itself. Point your browser like this: `http://website.com/javascripts/tabs.js`. Does the tabs.js script print to the page?

Comment: yup I see the the script when I go to `http://website.com/javascripts/tabs.js`

Comment: Can't reproduce. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/XBLAY/

Comment: @isherwood, I can only reproduce it when I deploy the code to a test server. It works find on my local host as well.

Comment: Right. So we can't really help. Show us the test server.

Comment: @isherwood. I can't show you the test server. My company is using it to deploy code before the code goes to production.

Comment: change $( "div.tabs" ).tabs(); to $( ".tabs" ).tabs();

Comment: send us the link to the live server

Comment: Figured it out. I need to use `https` instead of `http`which was causing some of my resources to not load.